# Perform action after returning value

Tags: cocoa

I was wondering if there is a way how to perform actions in a function after it returning a value.

i.e there is a method which returns a string. Now after the string is returned I want the method to perform another action like checking whether a condition is met so it can send out a notification or something else. Is that somehow possible?

The thing is that I am using a framework called core plot to add some plots to my application. Unfortunately this framework does not have a didFinishAddingPlot method. So I have to manually program a mechanism which notifies me whenever the plot finished plotting. When the addPlot method is called another method is called which goes through an array of values and returns a value for a specific index to plot. My idea was to put in  a "if (condition)" block to check if the index is equal to the count of my values array so I know that it is now fetching the last value. However it first needs to return the value before sending a message that it finished plotting. Otherwise the last value won't get passed.

Comment: This would probably require some form of message-passing system and multithreading to do what I expect you want it to do. Doing anything after a return is not only not possible but not very useful since the function that is calling doesn't recieve the returned value until after it has resumed execution.

Comment: If the purpose of this method is to return a string, doing anything non-string-related there is probably bad design.

Comment: @iJatrat: As near as I could tell from looking at the source, adding a plot is synchronous—when it returns, the plot has been added. (This is assuming `addSublayer:` is not doing something really, really fancy.) What do you really need to wait for?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as a function hits a return statement the function stops running.  You would need to perform whatever other action you want to do before you return.

Comment: Or after some amount of time (using a timer or delayed perform), or on another thread, or as an operation or block on a queue, or just somewhere else in the code. The last of those may be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to return a value from your function or method, which by definition returns control (as well as your answer) to the call site.  On the face of it, it's not possible; you've returned control, so you're done.

But you *could* spawn a new **Thread** *during* your method execution, to (for example) perform some cleanup tasks later on.

Since you tagged the question as Cocoa, check out Apple's [Threaded Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html), which will teach you about NSThread, POSIX threads, and more.